# configuration of Point Cloud Library(PCL)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, point-cloud-library

I followed this http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php for configuration. I am using 64 bit pcl 1.5.1, visual studio 2010 and cmake3.0.2 in 64bit windows7. While I configure, I get the following error.

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Found eigen: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.5.1/3rdParty/Eigen/include  
Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/PCL 1.5.1/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:38 (message):
  common is required but boost was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/PCL 1.5.1/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:344 (pcl_report_not_found)
  C:/Program Files/PCL 1.5.1/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:489 (find_external_library)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/LocalData/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

And is there any other method to integrate OpenCV library along with PCL in windows?

Comment: Have you tried this install which talks about opencv as well   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pointclouds/files/1.6.0/PCL-1.6.0-AllInOne-msvc2010-win64.exe/download

Comment: if it wants boost, better get it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same(similar?) problem in my environment: `Win7 Prof 64bit, VS 2013`.
I downloaded Boost library, unzipped it to `C:\boost_1_56_0`, ran `bootstrap.bat` and then `b2.exe` to build Boost from source.

Then I edited `PCLConfig.cmake` in `C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\cmake`, replacing

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "${PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty/Boost")
```

with my hard-coded version:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/boost_1_56_0")
```

that's around line 93. After that cmake finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I solved a similar problem by changing line 113 of /usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake from

```
find_package(Boost 1.40.0 ${QUIET_} COMPONENTS system filesystem thread date_time iostreams serialization chrono)
```

to

```
find_package(Boost 1.54.0)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a cmake-gui available from here : https://cmake.org

first of all, download and install Boost library depending on your platform (mind the architecture 32/64) following this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

then in CMake, add entries as PATH :

`"BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR" as example (C:\boost_1_59_0)
"BOOST_LIBRARYDIR" as example (C:\boost_1_59_0\libs)`

Hit configure again and your boost library will be found.

Hope this helps!

cheers